# Issues Calling a Method From another Component

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I am defining a method "`onClick`" in a widget called `main`, and then i define, in another component (`reportsview`) the following method to go from it back to the `main` view :

```
onMainView: function() {
        
        var reportsViewInstance = Ext.getCmp('reportsview');
        
        if (reportsViewInstance) {
            reportsViewInstance.destroy();
            
        }

        var mainV2 = Ext.create('widget.main', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            hideMode: 'visibility'
        });

        mainV2.show();
        

    }
```

When the above method is called (e.g in the `main` view) i expect that the `onClick` method is callable (because it is defined in the controller of the `main`) but instead i get an error saying : No method named "onClick" on Class.view.ReportController (which is where the reportsview is defined).
I tried with the following in the `Class.view.ReportController` :

```
requires: [

        'Class.view.MainController'
    ],
```

What's the problem ?

UPDATE : The main view is defined as :

```
Ext.define('Class.view.Main', {
       extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
       alias: 'widget.main',
       id: 'mainView',
       xtype: 'mainV',
       reference: 'mainViewRef',
      

       controller: 'mainController', ...
```

In the the `mainController` i have defined the `onClick` method which is normally callable when the current view is `main` but in the above code `onClick` gives the mentioned error.

Comment: Not enough information to reproduce the issue. May you post a little bit code and/or present fiddle.sencha.com sample?

Comment: Please see the update